# How to view line numbers in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to adapt to Visual Studio from the experience I have using Netbeans. Please someone tell me how to show the Line Numbers in Visual C++ 2008?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you'll find it under: tools - options - text editor - all languages - display - line numbers (this actually pretty nifty, just enabled it myself)

Answer (score 3):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->Line numbers

Answer (score 0):

Tools - Options - Text Editor - All Languages - Line Numbers - Tick!